# Realm iOS: Cannot Convert value of type 'Dogs.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here is my DBManager.swift

```
import RealmSwift

class DBManager {

    class func getAllDogs() -> [Dog] {

        let realm = try! Realm()
        // COMPILER ERROR: Cannot Convert value of type 'Dogs.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
        return realm.objects(Dog.self) 

    }

}
```

This is my Dog.swift:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var firstName = ""
  dynamic var lastName = ""
  dynamic var dateOfBirth = ""
  dynamic var lastFourSsn = ""
  dynamic var currentLocation = ""
  dynamic var dog: NSData!
}
```

I am getting this compiler error:

> Cannot Convert value of type 'Dogs.Type' to expected
>   argument type 'T.Type'

Seems like I'm missing something really basic here - because this is mostly code directly from the [RealmSwift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`realm.objects(Dog.self)` returns `Results<Dog>`, not `Array<Dog>` (a.k.a. `[Dog]`). The misleading error message is probably just the compiler failing to do a good job of reporting where exactly the type error occurred.

Comment: Such smart people on Stackoverflow